# Bugzilla Installation / perl-DBD-mysql

Tags: perl, bugzilla

While running ./checksetup.pl I get this error where the installation stops.

```
Reading ./localconfig...
Checking for            DBD-mysql (v4.00)     ok: found v4.018
Checking for                MySQL (v4.1.2)    ok: found v5.5.11

/usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: 
lib/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so: undefined symbol: is_prefix
```

Bugzilla 4.0.1 / CentOS 5.5

```
perl -v
This is perl, v5.8.8 built for i386-linux-thread-multi

mysql
Server version: 5.5.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

What's to be done?

Thanks,
Andi

---

Trying to run `cpan> install DBD::mysql` gives:

```
  /usr/bin/make  -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00base.t .................. 1/6 Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  Unable to load DBD::mysql

#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 21.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/root/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.018/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: /root/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.018/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so: undefined symbol: is_prefix at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
#  at (eval 7) line 2
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 7) line 2.
FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

As for `perl -e 'use DBD::mysql;'` this gives nothing to console, just back to prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something went wrong with the installation of your DBD driver, obviously.

You should probably install the Perl module from the CentOS repositories directly:

```
yum install perl-DBD-MySQL
```

But if you have a specific reason to use the CPAN client to install the module, it needs a build environment (i.e. a C compiler) and also the MySQL C header files on the system. Usually, you would do this by installing two additional packages:

```
yum install mysql-devel libz-devel
```

Now you can properly compile the DBD driver.

Comment: Fixed. Your post helped me to notice that I had mysql-devel 5.0.77 while the rest mysql, mysql-server were 5.5.12. zlib-devel was up to date. I updated mysql-devel and then tried to install again.. still same issue. I have deleted lib/i386-linux-thread-multi folder and then run the installer again and fixed modules and all dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the perl shared-object isn't properly linked against the libmysql library, which is most likely due to version differences.

You probably need to reinstall, possibly by hand, the DBD::mysql module.

One more diagnostic step first, as this should fail as well:

```
# perl -e 'use DBD::mysql;'
```

That should give you the same error, most likely, but if may give you more useful information.

If you need to install the DBD::mysql module by hand, use this:

```
# perl -MCPAN -e shell
cpan> install DBD::mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

If still fails there is another option, to install from repo using `yum install perl-DBD-MySQL`.
(use `yum search dbd` to get the exact name). This is faster than installing from cpan because the dependencies are installed automatically for you and not compiled from sources.

HTH

Comment: That's the way I installed the module. But this gives me the first error from the top.